# Delete lines that contain two dots, with characters between the dots

Tags: sed

How would I delete all lines (from a text file) which contain only two dots, with random data between the dots. Some lines have three or more dots, and I need those to remain in the file. I would like to use sed.

Example Dirty File:

```
.dirty.dig
.please.dont.delete.me
.delete.me
.dont.delete.me.ether
.nnoooo.not.meee
.needto.delete
```

Desired Output:

```
.please.dont.delete.me
.dont.delete.me.ether
.nnoooo.not.meee
```

Answer (score 2):

Would be simpler to use `awk` here

```
$ awk -F. 'NF!=3' ip.txt
.please.dont.delete.me
.dont.delete.me.ether
.nnoooo.not.meee
```

- `-F.` use `.` as delimiter
- `NF!=3` print all lines where number of input fields is not equal to `3`

  - this will retain lines like `abc.xyz`
  - to retain only lines with more than 2 dots, use `awk -F. 'NF>3' ip.txt`

Comment: I apologize, my data had some hyphens at the ends of the lines which were interfearing, this actually works incredibly well.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*$/d' file
```

Output:

```
.please.dont.delete.me
.dont.delete.me.ether
.nnoooo.not.meee
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

sed is for making substitutions, to just **G**lobally search for a **R**egular **E**xpression and **P**rint the result there's a whole other tool designed just for that purpose and even named after it - `grep`.

```
grep -v '^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*$' file
```

or with GNU grep for EREs:

```
$ grep -Ev '^[^.]*(\.[^.]*){2}$' file
.please.dont.delete.me
.dont.delete.me.ether
.nnoooo.not.meee
```

Comment: I apologize, my data had some hyphens at the ends of the lines which were interfearing, this actually works incredibly well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a `sed` handy to double-check, but

```
/^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*$/d
```

should match and delete all lines that have two dots with non-dot strings before and between them.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\./&/3;t;s//&/2;T;d' file
```

If there are 3 or more `.` print. If there are 2 `.` delete. Otherwise print.

Another way:

```
sed -r '/^([^.]*\.[^.]*){2}$/d' file
```

Comment: `-r` will only work in GNU sed while `-E` will work in both GNU and OSX seds so using `-E` would be more portable than using `-r`.

Comment: Works great when I run that by hand, but from a bash script, it wont work.

Comment: I apologize, my data had some hyphens at the ends of the lines which were interfearing, this actually works incredibly well.